# Set empty value of column before create new one in case

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have sp like this:

```
DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)

set @comando = 'DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW'
select @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + str_ValorVariable + 
CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%' THEN @archivoCargado + '.csv\""' ELSE '' END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = 42
```

That I want to do is to do another case:

```
CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%' THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable ELSE '' END +
```

But I want to drop result of `v_sCadenaConexion` value after create this new one with case. How can I do that? Because If I use case with query it just duplicate existing value . 
I want something like if `str_NombreVariable` exist get that value and create new one with my case sentence. How can I achieve that?

Problem:

```
Package.Variables[v_sCadenaConexion].Value\"";Data Source=0.0.0.0\BA;User ID=BAS;Password=000;Initial Catalog=BOS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=SS;Persist Security Info=True;
                                             "\"Data Source=0.0.0.0\BA;User ID=BAS;Password=000;Initial Catalog=BOS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=SS;Persist Security Info=True;
```

As you can see it duplicate value. So I want to dismiss first one and keep second one(CASE one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean or not...

```
DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)

set @comando = 'DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW'
select @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%' 
          THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable 
          ELSE str_ValorVariable + 
               CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%' 
                    THEN @archivoCargado + '.csv\""' 
                    ELSE '' 
               END 
          END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = 42
```